# Python environments in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My problem is that I am getting an error message when creating a virtual environment, knowing that the virtual environment is being created but with missing files that are not complete like the scripts>activate.bat , Activate.ps1,deactivate.bat(Why are these files not showing up for me?)

The error message is:
Error: Command '['C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\fastapi\.venv\Scripts\python.exe', '-m', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', ' --default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

*Help me solve the problem, I am a beginner in creating the virtual environment :(

[look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQW5g.jpg)

Comment: create the virt env with `C:\Python3.10\python.exe -m venv .venv`, use the full path to the python executable you want

Comment: why don't you only copy/paste the content of the terminal, no need for an image

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the order like so.

Delete the folder of the virtual environment you currently created to use.

Create a new one using the built in **venv** module;

```
python -m venv <name of new environment>
```

This is the built in virtual environment creator for python. I’d advise to run it in the root directory of your working directory to have easy access. But don’t forget to add to git ignore if git source control is in use.

On windows after creation, navigate to the scripts folder of the new environment and run the batch file `activate` to activate your new environment.

The pylinter of the vscode market place might even start automatically activating this environment for you if you have it installed and give it permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install venv of the specific python version, for example:

```
sudo apt install python3.9-venv

python3.9 -m venv venv
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command to create a virtual environment, where `python` can also include the full path of the interpreter to specify the interpreter.

```
python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

In vscode you can also use the command palette to create virtual environments.

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_using-the-create-environment-command*

*https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/venv.html?highlight=venv*